# SonarQube upgrade to 6.4: cannot display tests results on the dahsboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I upgraded my SonarQube from 5.4 to 5.6 LTS then to 6.3.1 then 6.4
On the version 6.4, when I click on the dashboard, I only see the projects' names but no results are displayed.

In addition I have a rotating frame of the project as if it loads.

Plus, When I click on the project, I have 0 bugs, 0 vulnerabilities .... which is wrong because when I click on issues, I can see that the project do have issues and I can display them.

It's the case with the projects analyzed with the previous versions only. I tried analyzing a project with 6.4 and the results related to Reliability, Security, Maintainability... are there.

Is there a way to fix this, ie to display on the dashboard of SonarQube 6.4 the results of projects analyzed by older versions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always upgrade by creating a clean install...

Comment: cold you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you have to install every new SonarQube instance in a new folder. Then you also begin with a clean data folder (see the G. Ann answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is planned for SonarQube 6.5 (see the [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-9375)).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a corrupted ElasticSearch index. Try the following:

- stop the server
- delete _$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es_
- restart the server*

<sup>*The time for you server to come back up will vary based on how large the instance is</sup>

Comment: I did the steps you mentioned but I still have the same problem with projects display.
Is there another way to fix it?

Comment: To clarify: all other parts of the interface are fixed, but you still get infini-spin on the list of projects?

Comment: Exactly, only the old projects. And when I click on it, I have 0 results everywhere. It's only when I click on issues that I do have the issues list

Answer (score 0):

I see, thank you for your help. Just to let you know, even when I click on the project , I cannot see the results, they are only available when I click on Issues

[image]